# Sql connection refused for PHP class

Tags: php, mysql, class, mysql-connect

If I use simple SQL-PHP connection to test if it can connect to DB like:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected';
mysql_close($link);
```

It works and connects witohut problems, but when I add it to a class it gives me an error Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'. This is the class code:

```
class Konektor {
    private $dbhost = "localhost";
    private $dbuser = "user";
    private $dbpass = "pass";
    var $link;
    function testcon() {
        $link = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
        if (!$link) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        echo 'Connected';
        closedb($link);
    }
    function closedb($link) {
        mysql_close($link);
    }
}
```

Comment: For the hundredth time: **[Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://bit.ly/phpmsql)**. They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the **[red box](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)**? Learn about prepared *[statements instead](http://j.mp/T9hLWi)*, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) article will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the class, you need to access the variables using the `$this` syntax. Modify your class in the following way:

```
class Konektor {
    private $dbhost = "localhost";
    private $dbuser = "user";
    private $dbpass = "pass";
    private $link;
    function testcon() {
        $this->link = mysql_connect($this->dbhost, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
        if (!$this->link) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        echo 'Connected';
        $this->closedb();
    }

    function closedb() {
        mysql_close($this->link);
    }
}
```

Classes operate a little differently in PHP than procedural functions and variables. Within a class, you'll want to use `private`, `protected` or `public` to define your class variables (properties) and functions (methods). To access the properties (or methods), you'll need to use the `$this->{property name / method name}` syntax. For methods, you'll still need to use the parenthesis at the end of the call like so: `$this->closedb();`.

Comment: Here is the PDO version of the @War10ck solution.
<code>
class Konektor {
 private $dbdsn   = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname';
 private $dbuser  = 'user';
 private $dbpass  = 'pass';

 function testcon() {
  $this->dbh = new PDO($this->dbdsn, $this->dbuser, $this->dbpass);
  if (!$this->dbh) {
   echo 'Could not connect!';
  }
  else {
  echo 'Connected';
  }
 }
}
</code>